# missing in or out parameter at index 1 oracle sql developer

Tags: oracle, plsql

i am trying to execute this piece of code:

```
SET serverout on;

DECLARE
  CURSOR products_cur ( p_category    NUMBER)  IS 
  SELECT PRODUCT_NAME, LIST_PRICE FROM products
  WHERE  p_category = category_id
  ORDER BY LIST_PRICE   DEC;
r_prod_rec products_cur%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
OPEN products_cur;
LOOP
  FETCH products_cur into r_prod_rec
  if (r_prod_rec.LIST_PRICE > 
  avg(select LIST_PRICE  
  from products
  where category_id = p_category))
  THEN
    dbms_output.put_line(r_prod_rec.PRODUCT_NAME, r_prod_rec.LIST_PRICE);
ENDIF;
  EXIT when products_cur%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP:
close products_cur;
END;
```

but the message i get is:
missing in or out parameter at index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cursor is defined with the parameter `p_category`. You need to pass in a value for this parameter when you open your cursor.

For example:

`OPEN products_cur(10);`

or

`OPEN products_cur(v_number);`